# Java Method is Undefined for Type Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I have a Ball class and a BallContainer class. The BallContainer class contains a LinkedHashSet of Ball objects, called `contents`. One of the methods I'm writing is called `differentColors()` which as the name implies, returns an integer value of the number of different colors of balls in the set.

Below is a snippet of the code for the method:

```
int count = 0;
for(Iterator<Ball> b = contents.iterator(); b.hasNext();) {
    if(b.getColor().equals(b.next().getColor())){
        count++;
    }
}
```

I am attempting to loop through the list via a Ball iterator, and Eclipse IDE is giving me an error saying the `getColor() method is undefined for type Iterator<Ball>`. To me this doesn't make any sense. b is an iterator of the Ball class type, so it is capable of accessing Ball object methods. I looked up the documentation for using Java iterators, and I saw that when attempting to print the 'current' element in a list or set, one would use the .next() method because the iterator is 'behind' the current element, so to speak.

So I tried modifying my code to `b.next().getColor().equals(b.next().next().getColor())`
in order to access the 'current' element's color and compare it to the NEXT element's color. And Eclipse yelled at me because `the next() method is undefined for type Ball`. Can someone please explain to me what is going on and how I can correct this issue? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you can call `getColor()` on an `Iterator` or `next()` on a `Ball`. It's also rather unclear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: You have to get the `Ball` from the `Iterator#next()` and call `getColor()` on that.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: @shmosel how would I go by calling the `getColor()` method on the ball element and the next ball element then?

Comment: this method wont get you `number of different colors of balls in the set` all this will do is count how many colors next to each other are the same. Are they sorted by color?

Comment: No they are not sorted by color @corn3lius

Comment: The compiler is complaining because of: `b.next().next()` . b.next() is a Ball, so the 2nd .next() is calling it on a Ball, not an Iterator.

Comment: You can't get the next element without moving the iterator ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be much better off using a "last color" variable and looking at one color at a time. Also, your equality test needs to be negated if you're really trying to detect color changes. If the set is sorted by color, you can use something like this:

```
int count = 0;
Color lastColor = null;
for (Ball ball : contents) {
    Color nextColor = ball.getColor();
    if (!nextColor.equals(lastColor)) {
        count++;
        lastColor = nextColor;
    }
}
```

If it's sorted in some other way, you'll need some other logic. I recommend that you keep a `Set<Color>`:

```
int count = 0;
Set<Color> seenColors = new HashSet<>();
for (Ball ball : contents) {
    if (seenColors.add(ball.getColor())) {
        count++;
    }
}
```